# app crashes after exiting?

Tags: android, crash

I am making an app in which multiple HorizontalScrollview ,Overall the app runs well but when the user exit Boom app crashes , logcast tells me that it has multiple markers in onPostExecute :

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.three_fragment, container, false);
    L1= (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    L3= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckTest);
    prog =(ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);



        booksList = new ArrayList<Books>();



        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.30.3/actors/book_tab2.php");    

        centerLockHorizontalScrollview = (CenterLockHorizontalScrollview) rootView.findViewById(R.id.HMscrollView); 

          adapter = new CardHomeAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_home_card, booksList);


        centerLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(TabThreeFragment.this, adapter); 

            rootView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));   


            }   
        }
```

onPostExecute :

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(result == false)

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    if(booksList != null) {


        adapter = new CardHomeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_home_card, booksList);  
       centerLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(TabThreeFragment.this, adapter); 
    }
```

Error :

```
03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at br.liveo.fragments.TabThreeFragment$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TabThreeFragment.java:344)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at br.liveo.fragments.TabThreeFragment$JSONAsyncTask.onPostExecute(TabThreeFragment.java:1)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4961)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    03-07 11:49:21.478: E/AndroidRuntime(9703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 344 of TabThreeFragment ?

Comment: adapter = new CardHomeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_home_card, booksList);

Comment: The answer from Chris is correct - the call to `getActivity()` is returning 'null` causing a `NullPointerException` at that line (please read your logcat more carefully). The cause is the `Activity` has been finished and the `Fragment` is detached from the `Activity`. As for 'multiple markers' error, this is *NOT* a runtime error - it's a compile-time error. You clearly have some problems with the syntax of some of your code - there aren't any mentions of this in your logcat because it is compile-time. Fix your code as it recommends and those errors will go away when you next build the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exit the application, and the post execute still has to be executed, it tries to invoke the activity to either display a toast or to create a new adapter. But because your application has been killed, the activty doesn't exist anymore so you get a nullpointer exception. Either check `if(getActivity() != null)` before showing toast or creating a new adapter, or kill your task in the ondestroy function of your activity.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
if(getActivity() != null)
{
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    if(result == false)

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    if(booksList != null) {


        adapter = new CardHomeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_home_card, booksList);  
       centerLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(TabThreeFragment.this, adapter); 
}
    }
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
  Assignment

Comment: thank you very much :)  error it has been fixed But now I have another error :      03-16 14:10:55.888: E/AndroidRuntime(950):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)